# Error with large numerics in dcast.data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, dcast

Given a data frame I am trying to cast from long-to-wide using the `dcast.data.table` function from `library(data.table)`. However, when using large numeric's on the left side of the formula it some how combines.

Below is an example:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(10000000007624, 10000000007619, 10000000007745, 
10000000007624, 10000000007767, 10000000007729, 10000000007705, 
10000000007711, 10000000007784, 10000000007745, 10000000007624, 
10000000007762, 10000000007762, 10000000007631, 10000000007762, 
10000000007619, 10000000007628, 10000000007705, 10000000007762, 
10000000007624, 10000000007745, 10000000007706, 10000000007767, 
10000000007777, 10000000007624, 10000000007745, 10000000007624, 
10000000007777, 10000000007771, 10000000007631, 10000000007624, 
10000000007640, 10000000007642, 10000000007708, 10000000007711, 
10000000007745, 10000000007767, 10000000007655, 10000000007722, 
10000000007745, 10000000007762, 10000000007771, 10000000007617
), B = c(4060697L, 7683673L, 7699192L, 1322422L, 7754939L, 7448486L, 
2188027L, 1061376L, 2095950L, 7793530L, 2095950L, 6447861L, 2188027L, 
7448451L, 7428427L, 7516354L, 7067801L, 2095950L, 6740142L, 405911L, 
4057215L, 1061345L, 7754945L, 7501748L, 2188027L, 7780980L, 6651988L, 
6649330L, 6655118L, 6556367L, 6463510L, 2347462L, 7675114L, 6556361L, 
1061345L, 7224099L, 6463515L, 2188027L, 6463515L, 7311234L, 7764971L, 
7224099L, 2347479L), C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -43L
), class = "data.frame")

df <- as.data.table(df)

output <- dcast.data.table(df, A ~ B, value.var = "C",
                           fun.aggregate = sum, fill = NA)
```

This will produce only 2 rows, `10000000007624` & `10000000007784` and everything will be summed up in just those two.

This error does not occur when using `reshape2::dcast` function, this method produces the correct result.

Is there a reason why `dcast.data.table` is producing this error?

Comment: Check if this also happens with the development version. If it does file a bug report. As a workaround, you can coerce `A` to character.

Comment: @Roland issue occurs on development version as well and have raised a ticket. I have found that `data.table::dcast()` does work as expected however.

Comment: I provided feedback in your issue on github, please feel free to self answer the question.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer so that it remains closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was raised on github and responded by @jangorecki and this answer comes from the `setNumericRounding` help document.

> when joining or grouping, data.table rounds such data to apx 11 s.f. which is plenty of digits for many cases. This is achieved by rounding the last 2 bytes off the significand.

As such my 14 digit large numeric's where getting rounded and therefore combined.

As @jangorecki mentions this can be avoided by setting `setNumericRounding(0)`. However, I personally have re-classified my large numeric's to factors. This make more sense for my particular use case.

Further to this @jangorecki also advises use of `bit64` package when dealing with large numeric's.

The original post on [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1747).